# c++11 in-class member initialization with this

Tags: c++, c++11, member-initialization

I have a quick question in gcc 4.8 with the flag -std=c++11 enabled.
I can do this and it works fine.

```
class Test;
class StupidClass {

public:
    StupidClass(Test *test) {}
};

class Test {
    StupidClass c = StupidClass(/*this is the part in question*/ this);
};
```

and i wanted to know if this is valid c++11 having "this" in an in-class member initialization like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write

```
struct Foo
{
    Bar bar { this };
};
```

that is no different from:

```
struct Foo
{
    Foo() : bar(this) { }
    Bar bar;
};
```

So if the second one makes sense, so does the first.

Answer (score 1):

it is valid but you need to be careful as this is not yet fully valid. Storing a pointer or reference is fine, using a member declared before the one receiving this is fine too.

Comment: It can only being used once "this" is valid the way it is encapsulated. Only way to get a hold of a StupidClass is through a Test. This just came out of me copying and pasting in the wrong spot.